# windows mobile: Check if network is available

Tags: windows-mobile

How do I check if the internet is available on a windows mobile 6.5+ device?

Thanks.

Comment: Is any particular language preferable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this. In essence, this is from the MSDN Tips and Tricks webcast of January 12, 2005. It's slightly rewritten to fit my own standards and completely untested, but you get the idea. Use as you please.

```
enum ConnectionStatus
{
    Offline,
    OnlineTargetNotFound,
    OnlineTargetFound,
}

ConnectionStatus GetConnectionStatus(String url)
{
    try
    {
        //
        // If the device is set to loopback, then no connection exists.
        //
        String hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        System.Net.IPHostEntry host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(hostName);
        String ipAddress = host.AddressList.ToString();

        if(ipAddress == System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1").ToString())
        {
            return ConnectionStatus.Offline;
        }

        //
        // Now we know we're online. Use a web request and check
        // for a response to see if the target can be found or not.
        // N.B. There are blocking calls here.
        //
        System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = null;
        try
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Timeout = 10000;
            webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            return ConnectionStatus.OnlineTargetFound;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return ConnectionStatus.OnlineTargetNotFound;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return ConnectionStatus.Offline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. It works fine except I was getting a very strange intermittent problem. Finally fixed it by whacking this in a "finally" block:                 webRequest = null;
                    webResponse.Close();
                    webResponse = null;

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of code that originates from the same webcast. Usage should be pretty straight forward. Although it works as a networkwatcher, notifying you when connection availability has been detected, you could choose to only extract the IsUrlAvailable function.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace RAMIS2.Classes {
    class NetworkWatcher : IDisposable {

        public delegate void NetworkStatusDeterminedDelegate(bool remoteServerReachable, bool internetReachable);
        public event NetworkStatusDeterminedDelegate NetworkStatusDetermined;

        SystemState nw = null;
        const string _remoteServerExpectedText = @"RAMIS";
        Uri InternetUrl = new Uri(@"http://www.google.com");
        const string _internetReachableExpectedText = @"Google";

        const int sleepTimeBetweenConnectTries = 15000;
        const int maxConnectTryCount = 2;
        Uri _remoteServerUrl = new Uri("https://demo.mywebsite.com/test.txt");

        bool internetReachable;
        bool remoteServerReachable;

        Thread bgw;

        public void Dispose() {
            if (bgw != null) { bgw.Abort(); bgw = null; }
            if (nw != null) { nw.Changed -= NetworkWatcher_Changed; nw.Dispose(); nw = null; }
        }

        Control invoke_ctrl;
        public NetworkWatcher() {
            invoke_ctrl = new Control();
        }

        public void Start() {
            // This only works for Windows Mobile 5.0 and higher, not PPC 2003
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(5, 0)) {
                nw = new SystemState(SystemProperty.ConnectionsCount, false);
                nw.Changed += new ChangeEventHandler(NetworkWatcher_Changed);
            }
            bgw = new Thread(DetermineNetworkState);
            bgw.Start();
        }

        void NetworkWatcher_Changed(object sender, ChangeEventArgs args) {
            // instantly test new connection status
            if (bgw != null) DetermineNetworkState();
        }

        public bool IsUrlReachable(Uri url, string expectedText) {
            bool isUrlReachable = false;
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = null;
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
            Stream responseStream = null;
            StreamReader responseReader = null;

            for (int connectTryCount = 0;
                !isUrlReachable && connectTryCount = 0;
                }
                catch (SystemException) { }
                finally {
                    if (responseReader != null) responseReader.Close();
                    if (responseStream != null) responseStream.Close();
                    if (httpResponse != null) httpResponse.Close();
                }
                if (!isUrlReachable) Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeBetweenConnectTries);
            }
            return isUrlReachable;
        }

        void DetermineNetworkState() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= ST.WM5.Version) DetermineNetworkStateInternal(SystemState.ConnectionsCount);
                    else DetermineNetworkStateInternal(1);
                    // invoke on GUI thread
                    invoke_ctrl.BeginInvoke(new NetworkStatusDeterminedDelegate(NetworkStatusDetermined), remoteServerReachable, internetReachable);
                    Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeBetweenConnectTries);
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
        }

        void DetermineNetworkStateInternal(int connectionsCount) {
            if (connectionsCount > 0) {
                remoteServerReachable = IsUrlReachable(_remoteServerUrl, _remoteServerExpectedText);
                internetReachable = remoteServerReachable ? true :
                    IsUrlReachable(InternetUrl, _internetReachableExpectedText);
            }
            else remoteServerReachable = internetReachable = false;
        }

    }
}
```